# How do I set a default selected tile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have this itemBuilder for some tiles that highlights itself when tapped but all the tiles are white when you navigate to the screen. How do I make a certain tile be highlighted by default?

```
SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.food.variations.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (widget.food.variations[index].selected) {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        } else {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        }
                        if (selectedIndex == index) {
                          widget.food.selectedVar = widget.food.variations[index];
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:
                              selectedIndex == index ? kPrimaryColor : Colors.white, //right here
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              widget.food.variations[index].imgURL.toString(),
                              width: 52,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              widget.food.variations[index].title,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are declaring `selectedIndex` variable, pass a default value to it.

```
var selectedIndex = 0;
```

This way, the first item will be always selected by default.